# Partial derivatives of multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble with this question and I can't seem to even figure out where to start. Would anyone be able to help out with this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}=A\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial \gamma^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}
\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}
\right)%(\gamma+s,\gamma-s,At)
=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y \partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}
$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial s^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}
\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}
\right)%(\gamma+s,\gamma-s,At)
=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}-2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y \partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}
$$
Thus,
$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial s^2}+\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial \gamma^2}=2\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}
$$ and we got that $A=2$